# Why is my bridge camera showing more and more faulty bright pixels over time?

Tags: dead-pixel

Lots of green and blue pixels are appearing in pictures taken with my Fuji Finepix S8100. It's always had these, but only increased with time.

Here's a picture that shows the pixels:

[image: Picture with green and blue pixels]

Trying to find what is wrong, I took a picture of a white paper at f/8 (you can see the faulty pixels on the right fringe of the paper):

[image: White paper at f/8]

and another one in a dark room at f/2.8:

[image: Picture in dark room at f/2.8]

I don't really know what to conclude from these. The lens is clean. Where could the problem come from, and can I fix it myself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Stuck" pixel appearing on every photo taken](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/64101/stuck-pixel-appearing-on-every-photo-taken)

Comment: Also [Hot, stuck, or dead pixels. What's the difference?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/87417/hot-stuck-or-dead-pixels-whats-the-difference) and some of the things following from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like these pixels do not always appear in the same location (comparing the rose and paper picture, for example). Therefore we can rule out faulty dead pixels in the sensor. As these are isolated bright pixels it's also unlikely that they are caused by the lens/optics.

My guess is that these artifacts come from the image processing software of the camera. If your camera supports storing images in RAW format, try if these bright pixels appear in RAW images as well.

It also seems that Finepix S8100 is already quite old and it has a small 10MP sensor, so it could just be that the image quality is not great by contemporary standards (compared to good phone cameras for example).

You can, of course, take the camera to a Fuji service location for a better assessment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was kind of afraid it could be that, as there does not appear to be software upgrade for that model and there is no RAW mode.